# Use firebase hosting ssl with aws node server

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently hosting my site with Firebase and have created a elastic beanstalk node.js express server to query API's.

*(Not using Firebase functions for reasons)*

I can't access my node server because it isn't https. `Blocked loading mixed active content`

From hosting my site with Firebase i get a free SSL. Can i simply add a CNAME of my elsticbeanstalk server URL to my DNS records to utalize firebase's SSL?

or Do i need to purchase an ssl for my whole domain?

Or are there better free options.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate provided by Firebase Hosting can only be used for content that is served from Firebase Hosting.

But it looks like you can [use free letsencrypt certificates with Elastic Beanstalk on AWS](https://piratefache.ch/lets-encrypt-with-amazon-elastic-beanstalk/).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll give that a go